# Why in embedded f.e. for SPI devices sometimes daisy chain is used rather than typical connection?

Tags: embedded

I mean, does it have any advantages over normal connection? Cause I could see in wikipedia that it actually is sometimes in use...

Comment: This question really belongs on electronics stack exchange not on stack overflow, which is for software.  But while you are here, the answer is some parts only really work with chaining (shift registers) others only work in parallel with multiple chip-selects (proper SPI). If you have a part which works with both then it is up to you which you chose.  Chaining may reduce the number of pins you need or may make the board layout easier.

Comment: Thanks, I will delete this question to keep order on this website. Didn't know that there is electric stack exchange tho...

Answer (score 1):

There can be several reasons why SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) slave devices are daisy chained:

1. SPI slave devices may not be able to connect to different SPI ports because the number of MCU (Microcontroller Unit) pins is not sufficient.
2. The number of internal SPI modules in the MCU may be less than the number of SPI slave devices.
3. In applications without high performance expectations, SPI slave devices can be connected to the same SPI module to reduce the number of MCU pins.
4. SPI slave devices can be connected to the same SPI port instead of using software-based SPI (SSPI) if there is performance expectation in MCUs that do not contain enough SPI modules.